# Placing rotated label on Form

Tags: c#, xaml, rotation

I am having problems correctly placing my object, i want to achieve corner ribbon, something like this:

[image]

Because my ribbon should be 1/5 of a whole form i devided form into 5 columns:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    </Grid>
    <Border Margin="0" BorderThickness="2" Height="auto" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFE12727" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Padding="0,0,6,0">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-45"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,15,50,10">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="NEW HERE?"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How should i set the margins, padding etc, so that ribbon on all resolutions remained like on 1 picture?

Or any different way to achieve this?

Comment: You could also put an image (png with transparent area) on top of your grid. This is of course only practical if the label text is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CenterX and CenterY properties to set the center of rotation for the object. In your case the rotation center is in the middle of the border - playing a bit with these properties and it should work

For example, if you wanted a 100 by 100 square to pivot around its center, you would set the CenterX and CenterY properties to 50.

by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform.rotation(v=vs.95).aspx